# Cannot build - unknown feature `proc_macro_span_shrink`

Tags: solana-program, rust, cargo

I've started to learn Solana and I'm on the very beginning. When running `cargo build-bpf`, I get an error like this:

```
error: could not compile `crossbeam-epoch`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name crossbeam_epoch --edition=2018 /home/karol/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/crossbeam-epoch-0.9.11/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="alloc"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=0c75772846040a4e -C extra-filename=-0c75772846040a4e --out-dir /home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps --target bpfel-unknown-unknown -L dependency=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps -L dependency=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/release/deps --extern cfg_if=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libcfg_if-1643e4a2c6efb510.rmeta --extern crossbeam_utils=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libcrossbeam_utils-9bec6a43634cd6a8.rmeta --extern memoffset=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libmemoffset-4fe6cc40ad2ab243.rmeta --extern scopeguard=/home/karol/repos/local/hello-solana/src/program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libscopeguard-83203493741a9def.rmeta --cap-lints allow -C lto=no --cfg crossbeam_no_const_fn_trait_bound` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0635]: unknown feature `proc_macro_span_shrink`
  --> /home/karol/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/proc-macro2-1.0.46/src/lib.rs:92:30
   |
92 |     feature(proc_macro_span, proc_macro_span_shrink)
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0635`.
error: build failed
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "program"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.9.9"
getrandom = { version = "0.2.2", features = ["custom"] }

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "1.9.9"
solana-sdk = "1.9.9"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

Running:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL
solana-cli 1.9.8
cargo 1.64.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating Solana CLI solved this issue for me. Refer to [this webpage](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) or run this command:
`solana-install update`

Answer (score 1):

```
cargo update -p syn --precise 1.0.99; cargo update -p proc-macro2 --precise 1.0.43
```

this work well for me
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2226